# How can I make Asyncsocket didReadData read multiple lines of data?

Tags: objective-c, sockets

I sent a multi-line data with length greater than 20. I'm sure of this because I've tested to get the data using terminal `cn` command. But if I read the data using asyncsocket like this:

```
-(void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData*)data withTag:(long)tag{
     NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[data length]]);
}
```

I only get a length of 20... I think that's because asyncsocket only reads the first line of my data, and the length of that line is 20.

My question: How can I read all the data? I don't want the asyncsocket to only read my first line of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to put this on sock didReadData:

```
[sck1 readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

so the read cycle stopped after the first line.